# Using ASP.NET Membership providers in console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, console-application

I am creating a console application that will automatically create users into a database of a web application that is built in mvc and uses the built in membership provider and roles for forms authentication.

How can I use the `AccountMembershipService` and `MembershipCreateStatus` classes from that in a console application??? I've added assemblies and refrences to `System.Web` and `System.Web.Mvc` and security etc but cannot get it to recognise those classes.

Answer (score 9):

Copy the relevant elements from your web projects `web.config` into the winforms `app.config`.

`System.Web.Mvc` is not required, and you'll also have to change from `Net 4 Client Profile` to `.NET 4` under project settings.

Comment: i have done that copied all the relevant bits from the web.config to app.config and changed the target framework still no luck however.

Comment: Error 64 The type or namespace name 'MembershipCreateStatus or AccountMembershipService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: seems as though adding system.web.applicationservices to the references corrected the issue.

Comment: It's also important to use `var provider = Membership.Providers["ProviderName"];` to obtain an instance rather than simply invoke the constructor if you want it to load the configuration from the app.config file.

Comment: include <system.web> in app.config

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) guide from MS. Be sure to place the  attribute in  section in app.config if you use multiple providers otherwise you may get something else as default provider and strange exceptions for provider assemblies too :).